# Mongodb cannot run map reduce without the js engine

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, swisscomdev

I deployed a nodejs app on appcloud with mongodb as service, I would like to use mapReduce for some queries but I got this error:

2016-10-21 15:45:52 [APP/0] ERR ERR! { [MongoError: cannot run map reduce without the js engine]

Is it supported on swisscom appcloud or what?

This is my controller (an extract):

```js
'use strict';

const mongo = require('../mongoclient');
const paramsParser = require('../paramsParser');
const log = require('npmlog');
const faker = require('faker');
const _ = require('lodash');

const datapoints = function (router) {

  const map = function () {
    var payload = this.payload;
    if (payload) {
      payload = payload.toLowerCase().split(" ");
      for (var i = payload.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        payload[i] = payload[i].replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        if (payload[i] && payload[i].length > 7) {
          emit(payload[i], 1); // store a 1 for each word
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const reduce = function(key, values) {
    var count = 0;
    values.forEach(function (v) {
      count += v;
    });
    return count;
  }
  
  router.get('/counts', function (req, res) {
    const filters = paramsParser.parse(req.query);

    mongo.mapReduce(map, reduce, filters)
      .then(function (data) {
        const topics = data
          .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
          .slice(0, 10)
          .map(function(topic) {
            return { id: faker.random.uuid(), title: topic._id, score: topic.value }
          });
        res.json(topics);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        log.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      });
  });

};

module.exports = datapoints;
```

```js
function mapReduce(map, reduce, filters) {
  filters = filters ? filters : defaults;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.connect(uri(), function(err, db) {
      db.collection(collection)
        .mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: { inline: 1 }, query: filters.find, limit: filters.pageSize }, function(err, docs) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(docs);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Swisscom's Docker based MongoDB service.

Swisscom started mongod with [security.javascriptEnabled](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#security.javascriptEnabled)

> Enables or disables the server-side JavaScript execution. When
>   disabled, you cannot use operations that perform server-side execution
>   of JavaScript code, such as the $where query operator, mapReduce
>   command and the db.collection.mapReduce() method, group command and
>   the db.collection.group() method.

Swisscom enabled that flag because of security. It's a best practise for hardening MongoDB. Swisscom is open for technical arguments and discussions about that. Maybe Swisscom misses an important fact?

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
   javascriptEnabled: false
```

Swisscom offers an other MongoDB service (not in docker container, 3 dedicated VMs with replication). There you don't have this limitation.

```
$ cf m -s mongodbent
Getting service plan information for service mongodbent as admin...
OK

service plan   description                                                                                                 free or paid   
small3rs       Replica Set with 3 data bearing nodes with 32 GB memory, 320 GB storage, unlimited concurrent connections   paid   
medium3rs      Replica Set with 3 data bearing nodes with 48 GB memory, 480 GB storage, unlimited concurrent connections   paid   
large3rs       Replica Set with 3 data bearing nodes with 64 GB memory, 640 GB storage, unlimited concurrent connections   paid
```

With this plan you will receive Enterprise version of MongoDB and access to [Ops Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/products/ops-manager). In Ops Manager you will see nice HTML5 graphs with MongoDB metrics. It's nice GUI frontend for [db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } )](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) with history.