# Why are my mongodb queries so slow (on Swisscom cloud)?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, swisscomdev

I am using a (small, 256 MB) MongoDB 3.2.9 service instance through Swisscom CloudFoundry. As long as our entire DB fits into the available RAM, we see somewhat acceptable query performance.

However, we are experiencing very long query times on aggregation operations when our DB does not fit into RAM. We **have created indexes** for the accessed fields, but as far as I can tell it doesn't help.

Example document entry:

```
_id: 5a31...
description: Object
    location: "XYZ"
    name: "ABC"
    status: "A"
    m_nr: null
    k_nr: null
    city: "QWE"
    high_value: 17
    right_value: 71
more_data: Object
    number: 101
    interval: 1
    next_date: "2016-01-16T00:00:00Z"
    last_date: null
    status: null
classification: Object
    priority_value: "?"
    redundancy_value: "?"
    active_value: "0"
```

Example Query:

```
db.getCollection('a').aggregate(
    [{ $sort:
        {"description.location": 1}
     },
     { $group:
        {_id: "$description.location"}
     }],
     { explain: true }
)
```

This query takes **25sec** on a DB that only has **20k** entries and produces **1k** output fields.

The explain info for this query:

```
db.getCollection('a').aggregate([{ $group: {_id: "$description.location"} }], { explain: true }):

{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {},
                "fields" : {
                    "description.location" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "Z.a",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : []
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : []
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$description.location"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

**[UPDATE]** Output of `db.a.getIndexes()`:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.a"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "description.location" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "description.location_1",
        "ns" : "db.a"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's doing a collection scan, have you tried adding an index on `description.location`?

```
db.a.createIndex({"description.location" : 1});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks - there is an index on `description.location` - any idea why it may not be using the index?

Comment: Just tried this locally and uses the index, can you run `db.a.getIndexes()` and update the question with the output?

Comment: Yes, I’ll update with the output asap. I have also tested this locally and it was indeed using the index. Hence, I started wondering if there may be anything special with the MongoDB setup in the Swisscom cloud. I read on another thread that they disable some `security.javaScriptEnabled` setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179448/mongodb-cannot-run-map-reduce-without-the-js-engine/40290196

Comment: @Chris that would be my bet too, looks like they're prob disabling something.

Comment: Yeah, I actually posted here to get feedback from the Swisscom engineers as this apparently is their preferred way of providing customer service ... hopefully they will respond as well :D

Comment: You tried to disable the `security.javaScriptEnabled` locally and see what effect it has?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible (supposedly only for the enterprise solution that we don't have access to).

Comment: I am about to consider to just rolling my own MongoDB from a Docker container as that appears to be working locally :/ I just need a decent backup solution then.

Comment: @Chris its not Mongo Enterprise for this offer. This setting has nothing to do with index

Comment: Thanks @Fyodor - that’s right this is not the enterprise db, but I‘m still amazed that a query can take max. 1sec locally and then takes 40s on their setup.